# Is it possible to use SSI and Apache to make a cms?

Tags: apache, ssi

I've been thinking about using Apache http advanced features and SSI to build a dynamic site with like a simple cms(lists most recent stories and uses a csv file to do look ups). Is it possible to abuse the advanced features of Apache and SSI in this way and is it feasible? I know that SSI offers a lot of power when it comes to conditionals, and that apache has some really powerful built in features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a wiki, a blog and a large custom Web site, with content provided by users, with nothing but Apache SSI and a few Unix commands, so you can certainly do it. If you're going to use a CSV file, you'll have to write one or more CGI programs to process it. They could be nothing more than shell scripts, but be VERY careful about using input from a POST or GET as variables in shell scripts. A hacker could put commands in them that *sh* would execute. You could use the exec SSI command, but it's a security risk in the same way as *sh*. It's best to write in a language that can access the content of environment variables directly, e.g. Perl, Awk, etc.

At one time, SSI gained the ability to process the *query string* directly. Unfortunately, in the latest version of Apache SSI, URL parsing is less powerful than it once was. Nevertheless, I think SSI is one of the most under-appreciated Web tools available.

Best of luck.